# Rails 4: How can I decouple logic in this long controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, controller, refactoring

I am using `has_secure_password` with a `rails 4.1.5` app. I wanted to decouple my login functionality from my `SessionsController` so I can reuse it to login any user from wherever I want in my app - for example logging in a user after registration, logging analytics events etc.

So I refactored my code into a `LoginUser` service object and *I am happy with it*.

The problem is that my controller still has some coupled logic after this refactoring. I am using a Form Object (via the reform gem) for form validation and then passing on the user, session and password to the `LoginUser` service.

Here is what the create method in my `SessionsController` looks like:

```
  def create
    login_form = Forms::LoginForm.new(User.new)

    if login_form.validate(params[:user]) # validate the form
      begin #find the user
        user = User.find_by!(email: params[:user][:email])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
        flash.now.alert = 'invalid user credentials'
        render :new and return
      end
    else
      flash.now.alert = login_form.errors.full_messages
      render :new and return
    end

    user && login_service = LoginUser.new(user, session, params[:user][:password])
    login_service.on(:user_authenticated){ redirect_to root_url, success: "You have logged in" }

    login_service.execute
  end
```

Everything is working as expected but the part I am not happy with is the tied up logic between **validating the form** and then **finding the user** before sending it to the service object. Also the multiple flash alerts feel..well..not right.

How would I make this method better by decoupling these two? It seems right now that one is carrying the other on it's back.

For your reference here is my `LoginUser` service object

```
class LoginUser
    include Wisper::Publisher

    attr_reader :user, :password
    attr_accessor :session

    def initialize(user, session, password)
        @user = user
        @session = session
        @password = password
    end

    def execute
        if user.authenticate(password)
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            publish(:user_authenticated, user)
        else
            publish(:user_login_failed)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What sticks out to me the most here is that `create` is a method with multiple responsibilities that can/should be isolated.

The responsibilities I see are:

1. validate the form
2. find the user
3. return validation error messages
4. return unknown user error messages
5. create LoginService object, setup after-auth behavior and do auth

The design goal to clean this up would be to write methods with a single responsibility and to have dependencies injected where possible.

Ignoring the UserService object, my first shot at a refactor might look like this:

```
def create
  validate_form(user_params); return if performed?
  user = find_user_for_authentication(user_params); return if performed?

  login_service = LoginUser.new(user, session, user_params[:password])
  login_service.on(:user_authenticated){ redirect_to root_url, success: "You have logged in" }
  login_service.execute
end

private

def user_params
  params[:user]
end

def validate_form(attrs)
  login_form = Forms::LoginForm.new(User.new)
  unless login_form.validate(attrs)
    flash.now.alert = login_form.errors.full_messages
    render :new
  end
end

def find_user_for_authentication(attrs)
  if (user = User.find_by_email(attrs[:email]))
    user
  else
    flash.now.alert = 'invalid user credentials'
    render :new
  end
end
```

Of note, the `return if performed?` conditions will check if a `render` or `redirect_to` method has been called. If so, `return` is called and the `create` action is finished early to prevent double render/redirect errors.

I think this is a big improvement simply because the responsibilities have been divvied up into a few different methods. And these methods have their dependencies injected, for the most part, so that they can continue to evolve freely in the future as well.

Comment: This is an amazing answer. More than what I had hoped for

Comment: Just one question @pdobb - the problem with my `LoginUser` object is that it requires raw password input as a dependency and I am finding it hard to pass that in through other objects that need to use my `LoginUser` service. Is there any way I could solve for this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow the issue. Why is it hard to pass in the raw password? I would think that in any login scenario you'd always have the raw password available. Maybe make a new question with code and link it to me?